# Problem updating UI using C# Asynchronous Pattern

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am attempting to implement the MSDN Asynchronous Pattern example shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wy069k1%28v=VS.90%29.aspx. In the example, the ProgressChanged event is fired with such frequency that the UI hangs while the events are being processed. Note that I changed:

```
int testNumber = rand.Next(200000);
```

to

```
int testNumber = 20000000;
```

in **startAsyncButton_Click** to better test this scenario.

The progress bar does update as expected, but all other UI events are hung. If I change

```
// Yield the rest of this time slice.
Thread.Sleep(0);
```

to

```
// Yield the rest of this time slice.
Thread.Sleep(1);
```

in the **BuildPrimeNumberList** method, the UI starts responding bit this defeats the performance purpose of using a thread.

Can anyone recommend an approach that effectively allows the UI to remain responsive in this example?

Thanks

Comment: This usage of multithreading isn't really about performance, it is about performing a long-running operation without locking up the UI. In a real-world scenario where performance might be critical (which is very rare) you could simply update the UI less frequently.

Answer (score 1):

This is a misleading example on MSDN.  For the scenario of performing work on a background thread and keeping your UI active and informed of the background progress, use the BackgroundWorker class.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: So for my education, how is it misleading. Also, under what circumstances would you use the pattern described in the article vs the backgroundworker class?

Comment: I would use the event based model or the IAsyncResult model (a 3rd option) for performing a single operation in the background like calling a webservice.   for long running or multi-operation tasks, backgroundworker was created specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Note the comments from the example

```
    // This event handler updates the ListView control when the
    // PrimeNumberCalculator raises the ProgressChanged event.
    //
    // On fast computers, the PrimeNumberCalculator can raise many
    // successive ProgressChanged events, so the user interface 
    // may be flooded with messages. To prevent the user interface
    // from hanging, progress is only reported at intervals. 
    private void primeNumberCalculator1_ProgressChanged(
        ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I think your computer is so fast it is producing too many events.

Try changing the reporting interval:

```
private int progressInterval = 100;

private int progressInterval = 1000;
```

Comment: Changing Thread.Sleep in the BuildPrimeNumberList to Thread.Sleep(1) accomplishes by preventing the event from being fired so frequently. Changing the interval does not. The UI still hangs

Comment: try making it bigger, 10000. If that doesn't work; in primeNumberCalculator1_ProgressChanged try putting return; as the first line, that should bypass the UI update, see if it still hangs the program. if it does, you may need to throttle the events further up the chain (eg asyncOp.Post(this.onProgressReportDelegate, e);)

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, or any other situation where reporting progress is getting in the way of doing the actual work, the key is to report progress less frequently, or at least to limit the amount of UI updating that is attempted.

This example already has a mechanism for that: the progressInterval value determines how often the progress event causes a UI update.  I'll bet the problem here is that reporting progress every 100 times is still too much.

Instead of reporting every X repetitions (which will not scale along with increases in processor power) it might be a better idea to store the DateTime on each UI update, and then neglect to update the UI again until at least 250-500ms have gone by.

Comment: Changing Thread.Sleep(1) accomplishes. It prevents the event from being fired so frequently. Changing the interval still results in the UI hanging